# What does it mean from a practical point of view to find a weak (or martingale) solution of a stochastic differential equation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Given a stochastic differential equation SDE the mathematical definitions are clear to me, i.e. we want to find a filtered probability space, a BM and a process which satisfy the SDE.
However in the real world we are given a probability space and a BM on it (e.g. the uncertainty on the stock market). Why constructing these weak solutions which are purely mathematical objects would help?

Comment: First concerning your question: there is a slight difference between weak solutions to an SDE and solutions to the associated martingale problem. I am not sure whether you are referring to the latter by saying "martingale solution"?
Next, there are different approaches to answer your question: a) you are not always interested in the BM (you are not interested in the noise, only in the process), b) strong solutions do not always exist! so perhaps it is a good idea to study weaker solutions, c) sometimes it is easier to prove existence of weak solution and strengthen it to strong solutions

Comment: Yes I was meaning weak solutions by martingale solutions

Comment: @MushuNrek you may post that as an answer by giving references for the three points you highlighted